# ffmpeg –i /data/1.mp4 /data/2.mp4 Unable to find a suitable output format for '–i'

Tags: ffmpeg

I have installed ffmpeg  ,why doesn't it work when I enter

> ffmpeg –i /data/1.mp4 /data/2.mp4??

Could someone help me to solve it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using a fancy dash (`–`) instead of the "normal" dash (`-`) that `ffmpeg` expects.

Try copying and pasting the following:

`ffmpeg -i /data/1.mp4 /data/2.mp4`

Comment: lol ,it makes! I just copy it from my chinese college's document .Thank you very much ~~

Comment: You're welcome :) I think we've all had this happen to us at some point.

Comment: Actually ,I am a Chinese work in China Suzhou ,I just cannot figure out this problem so I register this website...